# Using JSON in Eclipse

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I am a novice in using JSON, so my problem should be easy for you. Basically I added the JSON jar as external JAR, and tried to test it. I can make object but any method on it do not work. Here is screenshot: http://shrani.si/f/1l/GU/4elwJxP4/zajeta-slika.jpg

What do I need to do to make JSON code work?

Comment: So in essence your question is how to add a jar file to Eclipse?

Comment: @Hot Licks I allready included JAR file, and my code doesn't work. So my question is, what do I need to do, to make JSON code work in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse , navigate to

```
Windows ->Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> ClassPath Variables
```

If your classpath variable `'JSON_JARS'` is not present there, add it there, alongwith its location.

This should resolve your 'unbound classpath variable' error, if you have this error.

Moreover, put your execution codes in some method, or at least in main.
For example :

```
package test;

import org.json.simple.*;

public class JSONTest {

    public void testMethod(){
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name","test");

        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.add("1234");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("name","test");

        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        list.add("1234");
    }
}
```

This doesn't throw any error.

For the code which you have attached, if I am correct, there is no way for the code to   populate the object and list, to get executed. This is why you get those errors.